# SOAP and Sinatra

Tags: ruby, soap, sinatra

I am going to write a Sinatra app that needs to submit information to some legacy app via SOAP. The interface is simple and as far as I can see, the data transfer is one-way: Data needs to be submitted from the Sinatra app to the legacy app. So the Sinatra app only needs to do SOAP calls.

Which SOAP framework is best suited for this task?

[SimpleWS](http://rbbt.dacya.ucm.es/simplews/index.html) seems to be a nice choice but it is based on SOAP4R that is known to be buggy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [savon](http://savonrb.com). I haven't had a chance to play with it in anything serious, but have some SOAP projects in the queue, and have targeted savon as the first candidate.